# Generating DDL's using DBeaver through CLI

Tags: ddl, sap-ase, dbeaver, sap-iq

I'm looking for a way to automate the generation of **DDL's** from my database (Sybase IQ).
I found that **DBeaver** (Windows) can generate the DDL's and that it also has various CLI parameters to control DBeaver.  Is there a way to make it generate DDL code and save it to a text file?

Comment: For Sybase IQ,  seems it has its own DDL-GEN command line tool. Did you try it?

Comment: Sybase has a DDL-gen CLI tool which I use often.  But AFAIK Sybase IQ does not.  If it does, please let me know where to get more information about it.

Comment: https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc39001.1600/doc/html/har1355981355759.html  Seems SCC has.